# Unable to use Exception Handling(Page level and global level) in my nextjs as error.js can NOT catch error from async function when using App Router

Tags: reactjs, next.js, error-handling, next.js13

please have a look at my folder structure

[image]

`app/(site)/users/page.jsx` code is

```
"use client";

import React from "react";
import UserTable from "@/components/partials/tables/UserTable";

const users = () => {
  
   return (
     <div className=" space-y-5">
         <UserTable />
     </div>
   );
 };
export default users;
```

In `UserTable.jsx` i am fetching data from api and performing all paginations, listing etc and  using `try/catch` for all places.

For some specific permission we are getting 403 response with proper error message from `axios` API i.e. fine for me and i am throwing error by using `throw new Error('Some Mesaage');` in my nextjs But page is unable to move to `error.jsx` or `global-error.jsx` and still showing same listing page but it is throwing error in console and also in nextjs.

How to move page to error page if throwing error by UserTable component ?

**Note: I am using App Router with nextjs 13.5.2**

Comment: is your error.jsx a client component?

Comment: yes in my error.jsx i am  using  'use client' already

Comment: i think error file works only for server pages. can you remove `use client` from `app/(site)/users/page.jsx`, and then try it

Comment: yes i have removed still it is not working as if i am writing throw new Error('Some Msg'); in my users/page.jsx then its showing error from error.jsx but the same thing i am doing in UserTable.jsx and that component i am importing in my users/page.jsx and it is not working
i Have used manual ErrorBoundary also but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Since `async` functions could exist and be called inside the `useEffect` hook, the Error will be thrown successfully.

The issue is on the Error Boundary.

`error.js` is based on React Error Boundary.

Automatically wrap a route segment and its nested children in a React Error Boundary.

In React Error Boundary, there are a few cases that the error boundaries cannot catch errors.

Error boundaries do not catch errors for:

- Server side rendering
- Event handlers
- Asynchronous code (e.g. setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame callbacks)
- Errors thrown in the error boundary itself (rather than its children) Ref: https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html

As you can see, asynchronous code escape from the error boundaries, which is exactly in my case.

Fortunately, there's a way to resolve this issue by using `useState` to re-throw error inside the `useEffect`.

First set the error by using useState

```
const [, setError] = useState();
```

And, only need to add below code in place of `throw new Error('some error');`

```
setError(() => {
          throw err;
        });
```

It has resolved my error and i am successfully getting error page.